# What type of production/project framework is use with products with long lead times and high upfront costs, such as automobiles

Tags: project-management-style

I am aware that million dollar presses are used in stamping out auto parts.

I am aware that million dollar robots are utilized in assembly of autos.

I am interested in what production/project framework is utilized in automotive industry when proposing a new model or a major redesign of a model by an auto maker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Product lifecycle management (PLM) is used in Automobile, Aerospace and similar industries for new product development and major redesign

From the Wikipedia article: [Product lifecycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_lifecycle)

> PLM systems help organizations in coping with the increasing
> complexity and engineering challenges of developing new products for
> the global competitive markets.
>
> The inspiration for... PLM
> came from American Motors Corporation (AMC). The automaker was looking
> for a way to speed up its product development process to compete
> better against its larger competitors in 1985...
> Lacking the "massive budgets of General Motors, Ford, and foreign
> competitors … AMC began development of a new
> model, that later came out as the Jeep Grand Cherokee... The second
> part in this effort was the new communication system that allowed
> conflicts to be resolved faster, as well as reducing costly
> engineering changes because all drawings and documents were in a
> central database. The product data management was so effective that
> after AMC was purchased by Chrysler, the system was expanded
> throughout the enterprise connecting everyone involved in designing
> and building products. While an early adopter of PLM technology,
> Chrysler was able to become the auto industry's lowest-cost producer,
> recording development costs that were half of the industry average by
> the mid-1990s.

While there are many commercial PLM software, there are also some open source ones such as:

- [DocDokuPLM is a high end open source PLM solution.](https://www.docdokuplm.com/)
- [Odoo PLM](https://www.odoo.com/app/plm) - integrates with the Odoo ERP/MRP.